# Angular Routing does not work in distribution

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Angular routing works fine with node server ie. npm start, but does not work when I deploy the files in Xampp after ng build --prod

```ts
const routes : Routes =[
      {path:"", component: HomeComponent},   
      {path:"outstation", component: HomeComponent},   
      {path:"local", component: HomeComponent},  
      {path:"terms", component: TermsComponent}, 
      {path:"privacy_policy", component: privacy_policyComponent},
      {path:"select_cars", component: SelectCarComponent},
      {path:"select_cars", component: SelectCarComponent}, 
      {path:"press_release", component: press_releaseComponent},  
      {path:"account", component: AccountSettingComponent},   
      {path:"logout", component: LogoutComponent},    
      {path:"**", component: PageNotFoundComponent},
    ]
```

Comment: Empty path routes `{path:"", component: HomeComponent},` without children should use `pathMatch: 'true'`. I assume your server is not configured to support HTML5 pushState. You can try to find out by switching to HashLocationStrategy and check if it works this way. This would confirm my suggestion (imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})]`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer now the routing works with http://192.168.0.52/savaari/dist/#/privacy_policy, How do I remove # in the uri?

Comment: By removing `, useHash: true` ;-) I suggested this only to track down the root cause. If it works with `useHash`, you need to configure your server to support HTML5 pushState. There are enough answers for all kinds of servers.

Comment: Thank you so much @GünterZöchbauer